# cant download the image with Instaloader and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

I have made a insta profile pic downloader using Instaloader and Tkinter but whenever i click the download button some error Appears.
Below is my Tkinter code:

```
import instaloader
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("profile Pic Downloader")
root.geometry("300x200")

user_var = tk.StringVar()

def download():
    mod = instaloader.Instaloader()
    mod.download_profile(user_entry, profile_pic_only=True)


user_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Enter Insta Id: ', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
user_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = user_var, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))

download_button = tk.Button(root, text = 'Download', command = download)

user_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
user_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
download_button.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

And here is my error log:

```
$ C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe g:/InstaDownloader/InstaPPDownloader.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__     
    return self.func(*args)
  File "g:/InstaDownloader/InstaPPDownloader.py", line 12, in download
    mod.download_profile(user_entry, profile_pic_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\instaloader\instaloader.py", line 1156, in download_profile
    profile_name = profile.username
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'username'
```

with only instaloader, everything works fine, like below code works fine:

```
import instaloader

mod = instaloader.Instaloader()
d = input("Enter Instagram username: ")
mod.download_profile(d, profile_pic_only=True)
```

But when i use this with tkinter, it shows me the above error

Comment: You're passing a widget to `mod.download_profile`. A widget isn't the same as a string.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: try `mod.download_profile(user_entry.get(), profile_pic_only=True)`

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you so much, this worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a widget to `mod.download_profile`, and it expects a string.

You need to get the value from the entry widget, and pass that value to the function rather than passing the widget itself:

```
mod.download_profile(user_entry.get(), profile_pic_only=True)
                               ^^^^^^
```